# What does the word "this" in the brackets refer to?

Tags: meaning

> It is phenomenologically absurd to speak of the phenomenon as if it
> were some thing behind which there would be something else of which it
> would be a phenomenon in the sense of the appearance which represents
> and expresses **[this something else]**. A phenomenon is nothing behind which there would be something else. More accurately stated, one cannot ask for something behind the phenomenon at all, since what the phenomenon gives is precisely that something in itself.

(History of the concept of time, Heidegger)

What does "this" in the brackets refer to? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"This" refers to "something else." Specifically, the "something else" that is mentioned earlier in the text:

> as if it were some thing behind which there would be **something else**

However, this sentence is overly complex and even I, as a native speaker, have trouble parsing it. I can not tell you what the sentence means overall, although that might speak more to my lack of philosophical training than my lack of English skills ;). It is possible that the translation from the original German created some of this complexity, or that the sentence structure worked better in German.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the sentences are very hard to understand!!!